# Modify tpl file to print the path to the image instead of the image itself?

Tags: theming

I need to change this tpl file which generate images for a image field to print  the path to image instead of the image itself.

**This code print out the images. It works fine**

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden) : ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item) : ?>
      <span class="<?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"><?php print render($item); ?></span>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to print just the path to the image (not the image). 
**I tried with this code but I get a error message related to line 58. (see the error message below)**

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden) : ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item) : ?>
      <?php dpm($item); // I uploaded a capture of this dpm

          echo $item['#item']->uri; // THIS IS LINE 58

     ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object en include() (line 58 de
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lembassade.com/sites/all/themes/omega_subtheme_2/templates/field--field-im-genes-del-fondo.tpl.php).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of your devel output (and the error message), each `$item` is an array, not an object.

You should be able to fix it by changing the line inside the loop to:

```
echo $item['#item']['uri'];
```