# Print ALT tag from an Image FIeld in a Custom Field Template

Tags: entities, theming, media

I'm attempting to create a custom field template for an image field with mutliple values. My field name is field_photo_slidshow

My field template name is: field--field-photo-slideshow.php and I've got it coded like this to produce a Flexslider slideshow:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
<div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="flexslider"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
<ul class="slides">
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
<li class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?> 
<!-- <p class="flex-caption">Caption</p> -->
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And this does what I want so far -- creates and unordered list of the rendered images. But now, I want to add an optional caption, derived from the Image fields alt tag -- but I have no idea how to render the ALT tag from a given image in the above code in the field tempalte. That part of the code, in theory, would something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
<li class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?> 
<p class="caption">ALT TEXT FROM IMAGE FIELD</p>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Doe anyone have any idea out to print out that alt text in the field template code?

thank you,
Nathaniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install Devel module and use dpm($item); in your code, you will see the structure of $item. Alt is in `$item['#item']['alt']`.

See for example [Modify tpl file to print the path to the image instead of the image itself?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34474/modify-tpl-file-to-print-the-path-to-the-image-instead-of-the-image-itself).

Comment: This was right-on! Thank you so much, I'd been banging my ahead against the wall for 2 hours trying to find the answer, and I couldn't remember what the Devel module was called or its functionality. This was a life-saver!!!

Answer (score 0):

For me it works;

```
print $item['data']['alt'];
```

So for you rhis:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
<li class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?> 
<p class="caption"><?php print $item['data']['alt']; ?></p>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```